# Finding the remainder of a large multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, unsigned-long-long-int

I would like to ask some help concerning the following problem. I need to create a function that will multiply two integers and extract the remainder of this multiplication divided by a certain number (in short, (x*y)%A).

I am using unsigned long long int for this problem, but A = 15! in this case, and both x and y have been calculated modulo A previously. Thus, x*y can be greater than 2^64 - 1, therefore overflowing.

I did not want to use external libraries. Could anyone help me designing a short algorithm to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have mod A of x and y, why not use them? something like,

if,

```
x = int_x*A + mod_x
y = int_y*A + mod_y
```

then

```
(x*y)%A = ((int_x*A + mod_x)(int_y*A + mod_y))%A = (mod_x*mod_y)%A
```

`mod_x*mod_y` should be much smaller, right?

EDIT:

If you are trying to find the modulus wrt a large number like `10e11`, I guess you would have to use another method. But while not really efficient, something like this would work

```
const int MAX_INT = 10e22 // get max int

int larger = max(mod_x, mod_y) // get the larger number
int smaller = max(mod_x, mod_y) 
int largest_part = floor(MAX_INT/smaller)
if (largest_part > larger):
    // no prob of overflow. use normal routine
else:
    int larger_array = []
    while(largest_part < larger):
        larger_array.append(largest_part)
        larger -= largest_part
        largest_part = floor(MAX_INT/smaller)

   // now use the parts array to calculate the mod by going through each elements mod and adding them etc
```

If you understand this code and the setup, you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: I use them, but in a bad scenario they could be like 10^11 and 10^10, and in this case their multiplication overflows.

I tried the following:

`ll big_num_mult(ll x, ll y)
{
 if (y != 0 && x > C / y)
 {
  ll h[4], res = 0;
  h[0] = x >> 48;
  h[1] = (x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF) >> 32;
  h[2] = (x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 16;
  h[3] = (x & 0xFFFF);
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
   res = (res + y*h[i])%A;
  }
  return res;
 }
 return (x*y)%A;
}`

Comment: forgot to say that I actually edited so that it would work with large numbers like you said.